# Why ASP.NET action execution time is slow?

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core

This is my action code:

```
[HttpGet]
public object Data()
{
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();
    data.Sections = new SectionBusiness().GetAllSections();
    watch.Stop();
    data.Milliseconds = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    return data;
}
```

And this is a middleware that runs on all requsts:

```
application.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    context.Response.OnStarting(state =>
    {
        var httpContext = (HttpContext)state;
        watch.Stop();
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Milliseconds", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }, context);
    await next.Invoke(); ;
});
```

So, basically I manually measure time in two places. Once in the action body (my code), the other is in the action execution flow (Microsoft's code).

The `new SectionBusiness().GetAllSections()` uses cache. Thus the `data.Milliseconds` is 0 milliseconds.

However, the header shows 10 or 11 or 12 milliseconds.

And `data.Sections` is a list of 20 objects, each with 10 primitive properties (strings, numbers, booleans). So, the result would be a JSON that has 20 objects each having 10 properties (200 JSON key/value pair).

Why is Microsoft's code so slow and what can I do to troubleshoot it and optimize it?

Comment: You could read this document related:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#create-a-middleware-pipeline-with-iapplicationbuilder

Comment: if your codes were in middleware1,the time your header showed contains the codes which were in middleware1,middleware2  infront of next.Invoke();